# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' and plt.scatter()

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, csv, scatter-plot

I am having issues with the plt.scatter() function. The error message says 'Type Error: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray''I want this code to create a scatter plot of the x and y dataframes. The two dataframes are the same size (88,2) when I enter a sample unit into the code.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(x,y, color='black') #this is where I am having an issue.   
plt.xlim([0,10])   
plt.ylim([0,10])   
plt.title(unit)
```

Here is the a sample of the information in the csv file. (the numbers is the first column, material is the second, quantity is the third and so on...)

```
     Material: Quantity: Unit: Date:
0    B         1         A     43455
1    B         1         A     43455
2    C         1         A     43455
3    C         1         A     43456
4    D         1         A     43455
5    D         1         A     43455
6    B         1         A     43455 
7    B         2         A     43455
8    B         8         A     43459
9    B         5         A     43467
10   B         3         A     43452
11   D         7         A     43451
```

Comment: Can you put a small portion of your csv file so that we can replicate your issue?

Comment: I am not sure about how to upload a csv but I added a sample csv that should work with the code to the end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Matplotlib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) the inputs for `plt.scatter()` are:

> x, yfloat or array-like, shape (n, ) The data positions.

But in your code what you're passing to the scatter function are two `pd.DataFrame`. So the first column are the names but the second columns are where the values stored:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(x.values[:, 1], y.values[:, 1], color='black') #this is where I am having an issue.   
plt.xlim([0,10])   
plt.ylim([0,10])   
plt.title(unit)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
```

[image: scatter2d]